# How to pass to curl file with replace some sequence?

Tags: bash, curl

I have something like that (it replaces a special sequence in request and then it sends it with curl).

```
SPECIAL_SEQUENCE=My_value

sed -i -e "s|SPECIAL_SEQUENCE|$SPECIAL_SEQUENCE|g" file.txt

curl http://127.0.0.1:1478/ -X POST -d @file.txt
```

It does work ok. However, the problem for me is that it leaves changed the file `file.txt`. I could undo `sed` at the end of this script, but I wouldn't like do this (becase I often interrupt this script with Ctrl+C).

Can you give me some other ideas to deal with this ? In other words the final form of request can be known only during executing mentioned script.

Comment: Does this work? `sed -e "s|SPECIAL_SEQUENCE|$SPECIAL_SEQUENCE|g" file.txt | curl http://127.0.0.1:1478/ -X POST`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the file, modify it in the memory and pipe it to `curl`:

```
SPECIAL_SEQUENCE=My_value
sed -e "s|SPECIAL_SEQUENCE|$SPECIAL_SEQUENCE|g" file.txt | curl http://127.0.0.1:1478/ -X POST
```

Comment: I understand your intetion, but it modifies my file.

Comment: If you do not add `-i` `sed` will not modify your file.